# Volatile and LayoutKind.Explicit on struct

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mono

I've been looking all over both SO and MSDN, but have not been able to find anything mentioning the combination of a struct with LayoutKind.Explicit (which basically creates a C-style union in C#) that has a volatile field that overlaps several other fields, here's my code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ThreadContextId
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte ServerNumber;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte ThreadNumber;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public short Packed;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ThreadObjectId
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ThreadContextId ThreadContextId;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public ushort ObjectId;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public volatile uint Packed;
}
```

As you can see it's the last field in the ThreadObjectId struct which overlays both the previously defined struct and the ushort in the ThreadObjectId struct. Will this work "as expect", by which I mean how a volatile uint would work on a normal sequential struct or a reference type.

Answer (score 2):

I won't be amazed if I'm proved wrong, but my understanding is:

1. Reads and writes of Packed would have volatile semantics in the situations it would with an automatic layout (e.g. not if via `ref`, but would most of the time).
2. Reads and writes of ThreadContextId and ObjectId would not have volatile semantics.

Therefore, it would be much like if some accesses to a non-volatile field were from normal assignment and some via `Thread.VolatileRead` and `Thread.VolatileWrite`.

Comment: This is my understanding also, or as I'm expecting it to work, but I can't actually FIND this information from a canonical source.

Comment: I would think that "volatile" will only direct affect how the compiler handles instance of "Packed," regardless if that variable shares a memory location.

Comment: Bengie, well that's what I've suggested above.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: I wasn't sure when I first read it, but now that I've come back to it, it does say that. P.S. I wasn't trying to say you were wrong, I just wasn't sure if you were saying what I was thinking. I need more sleep.